# When does ROS support ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: ros-kinetic, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

help me please

Update:

but i need kinetic @@

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/296875/when-does-ros-support-ubuntu-18.04?/) by [minhsonpkmta@gmail.com](https://answers.ros.org/users/36367/minhsonpkmta@gmail.com/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2018-07-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 1):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

See related answer #q284184. ROS [Melodic](http://wiki.ros.org/melodic) supports 18.04.

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2018-07-10

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 1):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Kinect only officially provides packages for 15.10 and 16.04: http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0003.html#kinetic-kame-may-2016-may-2021

You *may* be able to build it from source on 18.04, but since it isn't officially supported if you have build errors you'll be on your own to solve them. Build from source instructions are http://wiki.ros.org/kinetic/Installation/Source

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2018-07-10

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1